# Weird issue with JQModal ,JQuery UI Tabs & ASP.NET checkbox list

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-2.0

I have a modal with JQuery UI tabs inside. There is a ASP.NET checkbox list server control in one of the tabs. I am facing a weird issue that if I set toTop:true in JQModal parameters

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testDiv').jqm({toTop: true});

});
```

when I run a server side foreach on the checkbox list it always returns false on all items. Even though if they are selected/checked by user on screen ._.

```
foreach (ListItem li in cbItems.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected) // <= Always false ???
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(li.Value.ToString());
            dr["ITEMNAME"] = li.Text.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
```

Removing **toTop** from the JQModal parameters solves the problem but creates another problem that in IE7 my JQ modal window is behind the overlay of modal, which might be due to the container div having CSS position:relative. Any clue guys ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that when you set the `toTop` option JQModal is taking your div that contains the checkbox list and attaching it to the `BODY` tag instead of its normal position in the DOM. Since it is no longer inside the `FORM` tag, then when you do the postback those values are lost.

Comment: you are spot on there. Any guess about a working solution to this problem ?

Comment: Are you doing a normal postback when that Insert button is clicked, or are you using an updatePanel?

Comment: In tab1 I have a button inside update panel, in tab 2 I have a normal postback button which refreshes the checkbox list on tab1.

Comment: As for a solution, you need to find a place in the code where you can get your dialog div re-attached to the FORM. I'm not sure the exact place to do this. Here's a page I found referencing your problem, but it doesn't spell out exactly what to do where (see the last comment on the page): http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqmodal-and-asp-net-updatepanel-in-master-page-do-not-work-in-ie7-in-the-content-pages-found-the-solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it solves half of the problem (checkbox list returning null always), now the button outside my update panel 'Insert' don't run the click event.